# how to add primary key column without truncating table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

We have received a requirement where we need to add a new column to primary key where table is having records:

```
alter table customer add (bill_to number(9,0),
CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY (bill_to));
```

In this case after it adds the new column to the table by default null values will be stored if table is having records, technically we cannot make this column a primary key, either table shouldn't have the records or we have to truncate the table, but we cannot do it in production,
is there any other way to deal this? please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in 2 statements by first adding an `IDENTITY` column and second making it the `PRIMARY KEY`:

So, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer ( value ) AS
SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;
```

Then you can:

```sql
ALTER TABLE customer ADD (
  bill_to NUMBER(9,0)
          GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
);

ALTER TABLE customer ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY ( bill_to );
```

And the table becomes:

> ```
> VALUE | BILL_TO
> :---- | ------:
> A     |       1
> A     |       2
> A     |       3
> B     |       4
> B     |       5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=de7f695bd2c4091eb8ae104d55d446c2)*

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it in a single statement.

You can achieve it using the three-step process as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ADD BILL_TO NUMBER(9, 0);

UPDATE CUSTOMER
   SET BILL_TO = SEQ OR ANYOTHER LOGIC FOR UNIQUE VALUE FOR EACH ROW;

ALTER TABLE CUSTOMER ADD CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY ( BILL_TO );
```